# Are pronunciation questions out of scope?

Tags: discussion, closing

I asked a question, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/how-do-you-pronounce-skyrim a while back and it was downvoted to all hell then closed many days later.  I'm not entirely sure why it's a bad question, as it is gaming related, and it does seem to be reasonably popular (though not near some other Skyrim questions) and #1 on google for "[skyrim pronunciation](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMU_enUS354US377&aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=skyrim+pronunciation)".

The question exists in many other forums around the internets, mostly with massive forum threads that were annoying to sift through so I figured I'd dupe it here with the blatantly simple Q and A format.

Are they off-topic?  They seem so rare in the first place, erring more on the side of in-scope seems fine.

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question? What's the purpose of this meta-thread?

Comment: I think he wants to know why it's considered a bad question despite being gaming-related and reasonably popular.

Comment: Check out the [discussion we had about this on Programmers Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/we-cant-pronounce-anything). It's not directly applicable, but the principle is largely the same.

Comment: @AnnaLear it is indeed very closely related, and like us, they seem to be far from consensus there.

Comment: In the light of [this recently asked question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/118500/27134), this topic may need highlighting or further discussion to formalise policy on these types of question

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any particular problem with these sorts of questions, as long as they can be objectively answered and are not just a matter of personal opinion. I certainly don't see them as worse than [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-megaman-left-or-right-handed).

Since your Skyrim question can be objectively answered, I think it's fine.

Comment: Voted to close the other question.  "Megaman is not drawn consistently, so if he were drawn consistently, how would he be drawn?" is not a real answerable question.

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't know about Megaman specifically, but many successful video games have an entire franchise around them in which such details might be clearer.

Answer (score 8):

I take exception to this question for a different reason: it's wholly uninteresting. The proper way to pronounce it has been said over and over and over again in [promotional trailers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjqsYzBrP-M) and [developer commentaries](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hYUIfK727E). If you take 30 seconds to say, "Hey, Bethesda must've *said the name of their game* when announcing it", it's self-solved.

And within the first hour of the game, it's said at least 40 times by various characters in-game. You can't avoid Bethesda hitting you over the head with the correct pronunciation.

To me, it's a question that reeks of Google baiting: whenever a question like that gets to stay open, it cheapens the rest of the site.

Perhaps if the question was a little more interesting and novel, it'd be a better fit. But I doubt, because generally games are marketed the same way as mentioned above, any pronunciation question would be sufficiently interesting for the site.

However, there *are* language questions like [what the actual lyrics of the gameplay trailer theme song are](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35031/what-are-the-full-lyrics-to-the-song-from-the-skyrim-trailer) that *are* interesting because—even though there's a *lot* of coverage about the topic—one whole verse is completely missing from the collective knowledge of the internet (or at least I couldn't find it after an hour of searching).

Would a linguist have a better chance at deciphering it? Maybe. But it's an interesting problem for gamers, and is just begging for a gamer linguist or someone with an inside track to Bethesda to rock that question.

Comment: If it's uninteresting it deserves a downvote, not a closure. And although I agree with you this information is easy to come by, I don't think it's super-trivial (on the level of visiting the Wikipedia page).

Comment: @Oak no, it deserves a closure. From [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/): "The minimum bar for a question is not “is this on-topic?”, but rather “is this *somewhat interesting* and on-topic?”." While I disagree Wikipedia is the only bar for determining if something is too trivial, the pronunciation of Skyrim was not notable enough to even make a mention in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyrim).

Comment: This cuts to the core of it. It's not a problem of on versus off topic. Bad questions are bad, no matter how 'relevant' they are.

Comment: Both the TV spots I've seen on Hulu never state the name.

Comment: I don't agree with @Oak that uninteresting questions that *deserve* nothing but downvotes should remain open :P.  Personally-uninteresting but otherwise good, valuable questions deserve upvotes (hover over the vote button).  IMO, generally uninteresting and useless questions fail the minimum bar for questions, as Mark says.

Comment: Why do people bother with SEO if "Google baiting" is something to be scoffed at.  If providing a clear answer to a real question without the bullshit of most forums is wrong, I don't want to be right.

Comment: The Are Some Questions Too Simple? blog post is from 9 months ago and I haven't seen any of the information in it implemented on the SE sites.  Is it still valid?  The LOGO question got deleted from SO, but "General Knowledge" is not a close reason, nor is making questions "interesting and on-topic" in the FAQ.  Note that I strongly disagree with it - the line "all questions are ultimately in service of the people answering them" sums up every disagreement I've had with Jeff since I discovered SO.

Answer (score -3):

I belive pronunciation questions for words relating to gaming *should stay*, but if it is decided that they do not fit, they should not be closed. Rather, they should be moved to the appropriate language Stack Exchange site instead. The [*Skyrim* pronunciation question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/how-do-you-pronounce-skyrim) would be then better served by being moved to [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I disagree. English.SE can help with pronunciation of words that are actually words. I don't think pronunciation of made-up proper names is within their scope.