# Are "Pronunciation" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

There are other questions about this topic, particularly [this one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/are-pronunciation-questions-out-of-scope), but they seem to be about a particular subject. IMO, the answers also appear to be a bit opinionated or subjective, so I'm just asking a specific question, to get a specific answer.

**Are pronunciation questions (Eg, "How do you pronounce [specific word]") questions on-topic?**

Comment: Is there a particular question that prompted asking about this?

Comment: @AshleyNunn I haven't asked it yet, but yes.

Comment: Is it about a word that is also used outside gaming?

Comment: @studoku no, that one rhymes with "duck". I know that already.

Comment: @studoku but again no. It's about characger names in game

Comment: I understand your issues with the other question, but the answer is not to re-ask the same question, which is essentially what this is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's about something specific to a game, this is on-topic. It has an objective answer and it's about gaming.

Bear in mind, however, that you may still get downvoted if it's extremely obvious, i.e. the character's name is said aloud in the game. This is one of the reasons people objected to the Skyrim question.

If the word isn't specific to gaming, it belongs in English Language Learners.

Comment: And if it's said quite often in game, be prepared to get downvoted into oblivion for lack of effort.